# nUnit and .core setting up DI for a non-WebApps

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

I'm new to .core, and am struggling to understand how to create an application factory within my nUnit tests (mainly for dependency injection, so logging and config can be injected).

All the examples I see are for web app testing, using `WebApplicationFactory<T>().WithWebHostBuilder` in `[OneTimeSetUp]` but I can't find anything at all from anyone writing tests for a console app, windows service, etc so I can't even post an example of what I’ve tried so far.

Comment: Does the Microsoft documentation on [C# unit testing with NUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit) help?

Comment: You shouldn't need di to test your classes. The required interfaces are passed in the constructor and you should mock those interfaces.

Comment: @junkangli, Thanks, unfortunately, it only covers the basics. The link of it covers exactly what I want to do but it is the asp/mvc example, I'm looking for the equivalent for any other type of app.

Comment: Like @Neil said, you don't have to inject your dependencies on unit tests. They should be mocked. 
You can find a pretty detailed example of the unit test flow [here](https://www.cidean.com/blog/2019/unit-testing-with-mocks/) .

Comment: Yeesh, we ripped mocks out about 15 years ago and haven’t looked back since, code is better quality and devs are happier, I'd get lynched if I suggested resurrecting them! I should have pointed out I was looking for a technical Q, not a design Q but FYI its integration testing rather than unit testing so mocks arent the answer unless its an exercise in self hate - but sure sure, I agree mocks might by an option in many unit testing scenarios, particularly simplistic ones.

Comment: Did you end up figuring it? Looking to do the same in functional tests (injecting services that support the required test data)

Comment: @OryZaidenvorm: I think I ended up with a bit of a hack in the end, nothing I'm proud enough to share :-) It was a bit of a fringe bit of code so wasn't worth wrestling with it too much.